# Appending in linked lists

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Repl:  https://repl.it/@Stylebender/LinkedList#index.js

So I know that the code is correct but I'm just curious how Line 21 works with respect to the `append method()`.

If we declare that the pointer `(this.tail.next)` should point to `newNode`, shouln't this.head.next be referencing a single newNode each time so that `this.head.next` would ever only be === `{ value: X, next: null }` of the latest newNode that is being appended.

I know this is clearly wrong and clearly not the case since when you run the repl and start invoking the append method multiple times, you get an increasingly larger and larger next value.

I guess my question is that why doesn't newNode in the form of  `{ value: X, next: null }`  just overwrite the head property each time we call the append method since isn't this what we are telling the program to do? (Even though I know this is clearly wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The head of a linked list will always point to the same node. When new nodes are added, they're added to the end become the tail, the head doesn't actually change. 
In your case when the first node is added, the head only changes because it isn't pointing to null anymore, it points to the new node that was just added. However it's value isn't changing. Any consecutive nodes that are added are tacked on to the end of the list. So when a third node is added, the second node changes to point to the third node.